# Displaying data in Vuejs Template a Multi data in one single cell

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

Hi how can I display these data in my vuejs

I'm trying to display this collection of data in one variable?

I tried notification.data.user_id but it's not displaying anything.

```
<div v-for="notification in notifications" v-bind:key="notification.id">
  {{ notification.data.user_id }}
</div>
```

```
notifications: {
  0: object {
    data: "{\"user_id\":44,\"body\":\"Thank you for registering your shop   'Alexis Corbi23' in our site!\",\"actionURL\":\"http:\\/\\/127.0.0.1:8000\\/shop\\/dashboard\"}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"notifications" is not a valid object. First validate the object, then iterate like below:

```
<div v-for="notification in Object.keys(notifications)">
   {{ notifications[notification] }}
</div>
```

One more thing, your "data" in "notifications" object is a string. So you can't access "user_id" key by dot notation from this.
check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cruz888/2z3wv9od/19/) for more clarification.

Comment: How can I get the specific data's on the string?